# glibc resolver vs Bind software

Tags: gcc, dns, glibc

Is glibc's resolver code taken from Bind ? I want to understand glibc's resolver. But its not clear to me what the connection is between glibc's resolver and the Bind software (from ISC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.isc.org/downloads/libbind/

> The libbind functions have been separated from the BIND suite as of BIND 9.6.0. Originally from older versions of BIND, they have been continually maintained and improved but not installed by default with BIND 9. This standard resolver library contains the same historical functions and headers included with many Unix operating systems. In fact, most implementations are based on the same original code.
>
> At present, NetBSD maintains libbind code, now known as “netresolv”.
>
> For more information, visit http://wiki.netbsd.org/individual-software-releases/netresolv/

The `glibc` resolver code is similarly based on `libbind`, albeit forked from a BIND 8 version, as documented in the file `resolv/README` in the glibc source.